# Link Drupal node directly to redirect destination

Tags: redirect, drupal

I'm using the Drupal [redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) to redirect some nodes and taxonomy terms to alternative destinations and this is working. However is there a way to have nodes/terms in Views etc link directly to the redirect destination rather than their own path?
Thanks

Comment: Not without using a preprocess function to change the link destinations.  The redirect module uses hooks to redirect the visitor once they reach the overwritten destination.  In order to link them directly without the intermediate step, you have to change the links *before they are displayed* on the screen.  The only way to do this is with preprocess functions.